# Exporting Target Definition each Repository wise

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

In Eclipse, in target definition editor I am trying to export the target definition. But I don't see any option to export it repository wise. That is everything is getting exported into single plugins and features folders.

For e.g. if URL_A and URL_B is added to target definition.

The requirement is to export URL_A in a different folder and URL_B in different folder.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Is this the 'File > Export > Target Definition' wizard or something else?

Comment: Yes about same, I need to export it each repository wise

Comment: if you copy the file and edit it with a text editor you can split the target locations upon multiple files and then export it separately.

Answer (score 0):

The target definition export wizard does not support separate locations.

The code that does the actual export is `org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.ExportTargetJob`. Again this does not support separate locations, but there does seem to be enough information available to achieve what you want. You would have to write your own export wizard using a new export job based on the code from `ExportTargetJob`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Also there is a workaround which Peter provided in comments works perfectly fine.